# Javascript - Block that should disappear on click reappear elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get three squares (put ramdomly) on page to disappear on click BUt for a reason I don't understand, some of them (usually the 2nd or 3rd one) reappear elsewhere on the page when I click on them.

They should just disappear.

I made a jsffidle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9949/

The code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">



    <div id="square-zone">
          <!--
          here appear the squares
          -->
        </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//randomly place squares
  $(function() { 

    var numInfoSquares = 3;
    var $squareZone = $("#square-zone");
    var $toAppend = $('<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal"></span></div>');

    for (var c = 0; c < numInfoSquares; c++) {
      $squareZone.append(
        $toAppend.clone()
          .find('.square').attr("data-target", "#myInfoModal" + (c + 1))
          .end()
      );
    };

    // place info squares randomly on the page
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    }
    $(".info-square").each(function () {
      var topPosition = getRandomInt(8, 70);  
      var leftPosition = getRandomInt(8, 92); 
      $(this).css({
        "top": topPosition+"%",
        "left": leftPosition+"%"
      });
    }); 
    // clicked squares disappears on click
    $(".info-square").click(function () {
      $(this).css("display","none");
      $(this).next().css("display","block");
    });   
  });
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

#square-zone > div { position: absolute; } 

.info-square > span { 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(http://cliparts.co/cliparts/ATb/jRa/ATbjRan5c.png) no-repeat center center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px; 
}
```

How can I prevent the squares to reappear ?

Comment: that is because of `$(this).next().css("display","block");` what are you trying to do here

Comment: You don't want any of them to reappear once they are disappeared ?

Comment: @HariRam exactly: i don't them to reappear at all

Comment: Then, its simple. Just remove/ comment the line $(this).next().css("display","block");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just remove that line from your code which makes it appear again

```
$(this).next().css("display","block");


// clicked squares disappears on click
$(".info-square").click(function () {
     $(this).css("display","none");
     //$(this).next().css("display","block");
});
```

Updated jsfiddle with commented line https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9950/

Answer (score 1):

that is because of `$(this).next().css("display","block");`.

Assume you are clicking on 2nd element then it is hidden, then you are clicking on the first element now that is hidden but when the above line is executed it will display the second element back as it is the next sibling of the first `info-square`

```js
//randomly place squares
$(function() {

  var numInfoSquares = 3;
  var $squareZone = $("#square-zone");
  var $toAppend = $('<div class="info-square"><span class="square" data-toggle="modal"></span></div>');

  for (var c = 0; c < numInfoSquares; c++) {
    $squareZone.append(
      $toAppend.clone()
      .find('.square').attr("data-target", "#myInfoModal" + (c + 1))
      .end()
    );
  };

  // place info squares randomly on the page
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
  }
  $(".info-square").each(function() {
    var topPosition = getRandomInt(8, 70);
    var leftPosition = getRandomInt(8, 92);
    $(this).css({
      "top": topPosition + "%",
      "left": leftPosition + "%"
    });
  });
  // clicked squares disappears on click
  $(".info-square").click(function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    //$(this).next().css("display", "block"); this displayes the next element back if it was already hidden
  });
});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
#square-zone > div {
  position: absolute;
}
.info-square > span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(http://cliparts.co/cliparts/ATb/jRa/ATbjRan5c.png) no-repeat center center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="square-zone">
    <!--
          here appear the squares
          -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, changing `$(this).css("display","none");` to `$(this).css("visibility","hidden");` also solves it.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9951/)